# Vaadin Button Alignment

Tags: vaadin

How do I add a button on the top right of a page? 
Here is my layout:

```
headerLayout
            hLayout1
                fFayout1
                     data
            hLayout2
                fLayout2
                     data
            hLayout3
                fLayout3
                     data
            hLayout4
                fLayout4
                     data
```

Does it HAVE to be in the page's layout in order for me to call the align method setComponentAlignment(component, alignment)? I was hoping to just have it's own build method and place it at the top of the page.

```
   backButton = new Button("Back");
            backButton.setIcon(FontAwesome.ARROW_LEFT);         
            setComponentAlignment(backButton, Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);         
            addComponent(backButton);
```

Although "setComponentAlignment" is reading as a compile error.

I simply want to add a button to the top right of a page.

Comment: what do you mean with "is reading as a compile error"?  aren't you calling this method on a layout?  is it a real error or just your IDE not unterstanding it? also most likely if your button is not on the top right, your layout there has not `setWidth("100%")`.

Comment: There is a red line underneath it which will prevent it from running. Layout is set to 100%. Still no "back button" at top right.

Comment: it it does not compile, then it's an error. you can not call a method on an object, that does not have that method. add the button to the layout and call setComponentAlignment *on that layout*

Comment: like this? 
topLayout.setComponentAlignment(backButton, Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);
Because I'm still not seeing it.

Comment: is `backButton` part of that layout? is `TOP_RIGHT` a static import?  why don't simply try it out and if there are new errors etc edit your questions with your new insights.

Comment: so it goes like this: topLayout surrounds back button alone at the top. Then one  mainLayout inside 4 horizontalLayouts inside 4 form layouts.